# CSV join from command line

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I have two csv file, and I would like to "merge" them and enrich the CSV1 with the data from CSV2. Both of them have the same B column.

CSV1:

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,,
1,2,3,,
1,2,3,,
```

CSV2:

```
B,D,E
2,4,5
2,4,5
2,4,5
```

I would like to have:

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Which is the best way to do this? Consider the files have 2mln of rows.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I was thinkg about removing from CSV1 column D and E with cut -d, -f1,2,3 and column B from CSV2 with cut -d, -f4,5 and then I was searching for some sort of awk in order to add the two columns of CSV2 at the end of CSV1

Comment: there is a tool for this already. `man join` and search here for 100's of examples `[linux] [bash] join`. Good luck.

Comment: Do you always match line k from CVS1 with line k from CVS2 or do you look for matching fields B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract columns 1 to 3 from `CSV1`, and 2 and 3 from `CSV2` using `cut`, combine them using `paste` with custom delimiter `,`.

```
$ paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1-3 CSV1) <(cut -d, -f2,3 CSV2)
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk looping `file1` and using `getline` to read from `file2`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","                                   # separators
    file="file2"                                 # set file2 name
}
{
    printf "%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$3                   # output from file1
    print (getline < file > 0? OFS $2 OFS$3:"")  # and from file2 if records left
}
END {                                            # after processing file1...
    while(getline < file)                        # continue with lines from...
        print "","","",$2,$3                     # file2 if any left
}' file1
```

Output if `file2` > `file1` (> meaning the number of records):

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
,,,4,5
```

and if `file1`>`file2`:

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3
```